# Did buddha accepted Brahman?

Tags: philosophy, god

Did buddha accepted Brahman. The supreme reality according to hindusim.

Or any perfect Supreme God.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of several previous questions tagged [tag:god].

Comment: Buddha gave a teaching to Maha-Brahma, so yes: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/jootla/wheel414.html (this article summarises material from the Pali Brahmajala Sutta). Buddha gave an account that the cosmos is eternal, and there can have been no one Creator, or supreme consciousness. Compare though, to the Dharmakaya.